# What determines the order of `require` calls in babel-transpiled scripts?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

So, my workflow up to this point was to put

`import "babel-polyfill";`

when using features like `async`/`await` to ask babel to include the regenerator runtime in the transpilation.

I see the the following problems for users requiring my module:

- The user is in an ES2015 environment and transpiles his code with `babel-polyfill`, too. Since `babel-polyfill` can only be required once, he will not be able to use my module at all.
- If I thus choose **not** to include `babel-polyfill`, babel doesn't know that the module *does* require `babel-polyfill` and won't respect that in the generated `require` order (at least that's what I think happens).

I've recently created an npm module that does not come with `babel-polyfill`, but requires the user to include `babel-polyfill` before calling `require` on my npm module, since it uses `async` and `await`.

Thus, in my current project, I'd like to use my module like so in `index.js`:

```
import "babel-polyfill";
import Server from "./Server";
import foo from "bar";
import baz from "qux";
```

where `Server` is a class that extends my module that requires `babel-polyfill`.

However, the transpilation of `index.js` starts like this:

```
!function(e, r) {
  if ("function" == typeof define && define.amd)
      define(["bar", "qux", "./Server", "babel-polyfill"], r);
  else if ("undefined" != typeof exports)
      r(require("bar"), require("qux"), require("./Server"), require("babel-polyfill"));
  // etc.
}();
```

Here, I can clearly see that `./Server` is required **before** `babel-polyfill`, although my ES2015 `import` syntax asks for the opposite. In fact, the entire order is mixed up.

That's why I'm getting the error:

```
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

How can I tell babel to respect the order in my source?

Comment: It's entirely possible that the order is just badly-handled. Not many people use the AMD output of Babel. When making redistributable modules, we generally recommend using `babel-runtime` over making users load the polyfill, but that also has trouble with AMD setups.

Comment: @loganfsmyth To be exact, I'm using the UMD output, just to support every environment. For now, I could work around this issue by creating a new file that only imports `babel-polyfill` and `index.js` (which is not a solution I'm happy with). With just two imports, the order seems correct. From what you're saying, it seems like making the bridge from `import` to `require` will rarely even be worth the effort in the future…

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you can't tell Babel to respect the order of your source - it will always hoist the imports and evaluate everything else afterwards. The only way seems to be switching to require when you want to ensure evaluation of some code (usually global assignments) first. As per my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40846655/1120969).

Numerous [issues](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1371) raised (and closed/rejected) against Babel relating to this.